# npm csv-batch finishes before batch execution functions are finished

Tags: node.js, csv, aws-lambda, promise

I am using the `csv-batch` npm package and everything runs just fine, however, I am working on processing very large CSV files and adding those records to a database. The batching runs as it should, however; it seems as though it processes the entire CSV file, without running the `batchExecution` function for all of the CSV file. I have wrapped it in async functions and promises, as the `csv-batch` docs stated, but here are the results for my CSV file:

csv rows and records: 9,799,912

Rows added to database: 980,000

Here is my code:

```
const csvBatch = require('csv-batch');

pgClient.connect()

var insertBatchToDatabase = async function(rows){
  const streamPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
    let queryString = `INSERT INTO users (${columnString}) VALUES %L`;
    let formatQuery = format(queryString, rows);
    resolve(pgQuery(formatQuery))
  })
  await streamPromise;
};

module.exports.handler = async (file) => {
  const streamPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {      
    let stream = readStream(file)
    csvBatch(stream, {
      batch: true,
      batchSize: 2000,
      batchExecution: (batch) => insertBatchToDatabase(batch)
    }).then((results) => {
      console.log(results)
      console.log('Done!')
    });
  });
  await streamPromise;
};
```

Here are the results of the console log when the batch is done:

```
{ totalRecords: 9799911, data: [], errors: [] }
Done!
```

Again, I cannot figure out why all my batches are not running properly... If I bump up my batched jobs, I will see more records in my database, but still no where nears what I need to see and I would like to keep my batch size low. If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate them!

Answer (score 0):

As csvBatch returns a promise you don't need to warp it inside another promise (you are not calling resolve or reject anyway) just use

```
module.exports.handler = async (file) => {
    
    let stream = readStream(file)
    await csvBatch(stream, {
      batch: true,
      batchSize: 2000,
      batchExecution: (batch) => insertBatchToDatabase(batch)
    });
};
```

or call `resolve` in your `then` block otherwise your lambda stops executing with pending promises.

I cant run your code but you might also `await` the result here too

```
batchExecution: async (batch) => await insertBatchToDatabase(batch)
```

Further you can get rid of the await here as long as you `await` the result outside.

```
var insertBatchToDatabase = async function(rows){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
    let queryString = `INSERT INTO users (${columnString}) VALUES %L`;
    let formatQuery = format(queryString, rows);
    resolve(pgQuery(formatQuery))
  })
};
```